# Replace a string within a string in PHP

Tags: php, string, replace

I want to replace a string within a string in PHP. It should find exact match.
For e.g if there's a string

`$string = "a b cd e f"`

my function would be like

`replace("a b c","1 2 3",$string)`

Any way this can be accomplished in PHP? I have tried str_replace() already.

Comment: And what is the problem with `str_replace()`?

Comment: You need to assign the result of the replace to a variable. It won't change the variable `$string` itself.

Comment: what do you mean by "replace a string within a string" ?

Comment: [str_replace() works just fine.](http://3v4l.org/XcUZq).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$string = str_replace("a b c", "1 2 3", $string);` should work.

Comment: [It does indeed!](http://3v4l.org/XcUZq)